# Android onConfigurationChanged not being called

Tags: java, android, configuration, orientation

I am having trouble with telling Android to not call `onCreate()` when the orientation changes. I have added `android:configChanges="orientation"` to my manifest but still when the orientation changes `onCreate()` is called. Here is my code.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="SearchMenuActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:configChanges="orientation"></activity>
```

SearchMenuActivity.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Set the current layout to the search_menu
    setContentView(R.layout.search_menu_activity);

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() Called");
}
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    //don't reload the current page when the orientation is changed
    Log.d(TAG, "onConfigurationChanged() Called");
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

And my LogCat Output

```
06-23 12:33:20.327: DEBUG/APP(2905): onCreate() Called
//Orientation Changes
06-23 12:33:23.842: DEBUG/APP(2905): onCreate() Called
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

A couple of things to try:

`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"` rather than `android:configChanges="orientation"`

Ensure that you are not calling `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` anywhere. This will cause onConfigurationChange() to not fire.

Check that you are not using `android:screenOrientation` in your manifest.

If none of that works, read through the Android doc on handling runtime changes and make sure you are doing everything correctly. There may be something somewhere else in your code that's causing the problem. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

EDIT: As derrik pointed out, I assumed that you were changing the configuration with the accelerometer detecting what way the device was facing. If you want the configuration to change as the keyboard is shown/hidden the configChanges in the manifest must include `keyboardHidden` as well.

Comment: for me, the trick was to use 
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"

Answer (score 83):

This was my gremlin for the ~same problem:

> Caution: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the "screen size"
> also changes when the device switches between portrait and landscape
> orientation. Thus, if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to
> orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher (as
> declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), you
> must include the "screenSize" value in addition to the "orientation"
> value. That is, you must decalare
> android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize". However, if your
> application targets API level 12 or lower, then your activity always
> handles this configuration change itself (this configuration change
> does not restart your activity, even when running on an Android 3.2 or
> higher device).

(From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

TL;DR: add "|screenSize" to android:configChanges="orientation" for API 14+

Comment: Awesome...after changing my targetSdkVersion from 8 to 14 I was wondering why onConfigurationChanged() was not being called.

Answer (score 10):

Try use this one.....

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

Answer (score 5):

You should change the configChanges entry in AndroidManifest.xml to:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Otherwise, sliding the keyboard doesn't trigger onConfigurationChange() even though the orientation changes. I just tested this on my HTC Desire Z.

Comment: In my case it only worked when I added "|screenSize".

Comment: this answer is no longer valid, due to changes in the sdk

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your manifest to each activity.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Then, override `onConfigurationChanged` on your activity as such

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Manifest:

```
<activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
</activity>
```

Activity & Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    Log.d(TAG, "onConfigurationChanged  " +
               (newConfig.orientation
                == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
                ? "landscape" : "portrait"));
}
```

Output:

> ```
> 10-29 21:53:26.951 D/FragmentOne: onConfigurationChanged landscape
>
> 10-29 21:53:26.951 D/MainActivity:onConfigurationChanged landscape
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't triggering in my `Fragment` (`Fragments` aren't registered in the `AndroidManifest.xml`) so I had to move it to the `Activity` managing my `Fragment`, in my case the `TabsPagerActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Few things can be cross check:

*In my case I was tracking language change of device using the onConfigurationChanged.*

Few things need to know about onConfigurationChanged is there is some difference in behavious between onConfigurationChanged of Activity and Application.

**When you change the configuration of device the Application level onConfigurationChanged will be call automatically and immediately but onConfigurationChanged of activity will call when you navigate to that activity.**

and another thing is only locale in manifest will not work sometime So you have declare other config change event along with the locale(in my case) that should be like **android:configChanges="layoutDirection|locale"**