# Issue in showing activity on change of screen orientation

Tags: android

Actually i have created an simple app in which i want to show another activity on change of screen orientation. I have gone gone through the documentation and example given in stack overflow and by using this i have generated my app and its work fine. But my only doubt is, if in the manifest file inside the activity tag of my main activity, if i used `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` and then run the app, then on change of screen orientation my next activity doesn't open, but if i remove this code from the manifest then it works fine.

So my question is if i want my main activity always to open in portrait mode the for that i should have to use this code in the manifest of main activity..and if i do so then on change of screen my next activity is not open.

So can anyone help me to solve this out. The code i have used is:

**code in manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ChartEngineActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

**code in main activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
     }

     @Override
     public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
     {
         super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
         Intent intentNotes = new Intent(this, ChartEngineActivity.class);
         this.startActivity(intentNotes);   
         finish();
     }
}
```

Comment: remove this ` android:screenOrientation="portrait"` bez your Activity always open in portrait mode so `onConfigurationChanged` not called

Comment: I think u did not understand my question..i know it will work if i remove android:screenOrientation="portrait", but let consider a situation..if the user open my app by taking its phone in landscape mode, then what happend my main activity will also open in landscape mode. so to open my main activity always in portrait mode i used this. So my question is is it possible to do my work by not replacing this code.

Comment: Anshuman, set screen Orientation in `onCreate` of `MainActivity` by code not static in manifest file

Answer (score 0):

change screenOrientation by code in  MainActivity like this :

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            int getConf=this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

           if(getConf==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
           {
              // this.setRequestedOrientation(
                 //   ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
           else
           {

               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               this.setRequestedOrientation(
                        ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
           }

               setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }
    }


@Override
     public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
     {
         super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
         Intent intentNotes = new Intent(this, ChartEngineActivity.class);
         this.startActivity(intentNotes);   
         finish();
     }
```

Comment: @imrankhanthis will not work i think... see this link..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457659/android-onconfigurationchanged-not-being-called

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

use

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"

Portrait orientation, but can be either normal or reverse portrait based on the device sensor. Added in API level 9.
```

may be this can help a bit...
this will call

```
onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) also..
```

Answer (score 0):

first dont change anything about orientation in your manifest... and dont fix the orientation also..
then in oncreate
do like this

```
    @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    int k=getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
              if(k==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
                  Intent intentNotes = new Intent(this, ChartEngineActivity.class);
     this.startActivity(intentNotes);   
     finish();
    }
    @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
 {
     super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
     if(k==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
                  Intent intentNotes = new Intent(this, ChartEngineActivity.class);
     this.startActivity(intentNotes);   
     finish();
  }
 }

    }
```

Comment: where i should write this code inside onCreate() or inside onConfigurationChanged() of the main activity. In my manifest file should i keep android:screenOrientaion="portrait". what is infra here? if possible can u show it in my code

Comment: in manifest keep screenOrientaion="portrait" and in oncreate of your activity add this code... and let me know if this worked... it worked for me now.. I tried it..

Comment: bool in while loop is true or false..is there any need of onConfigurationChanged() methos now

Comment: I write the code it doesn't work and while debuging i found that when i put it in landscape mode it goes to while loop but doesn't satisfy the if conditions...anything else need to be do in my manifest file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9181/discussion-between-raju-and-anshuman)

Answer (score 0):

Let assume you have total 3 activities and they are Main, Activity1 and Activity2.

And you first declare all the three activities in the manifest but **do not set the attribute for *Configuration* and *screen orientation*.**

Suppose your Main Activity is starting activity1.

Now come to Activity1.
Activity1 is in portrait mode and displaying listview for example.
So `onCreate()` method of Activity1 check the orientation of the activity, If orientation is in Landscape mode just start the Activity2 and finish the Activity1 else display listview in the Activity1.And also add one more thing in the `onConfigurationChanged` method check the new configuration and if it is landscape mode start Activity2 and finish the Activity1.

Now come to Activity2. Activity2 is in Landscape mode and it is displaying a Gridview for example.
So `onCreate()` method of Activity2 check the orientation, If orientation is Portrait then start Activity1 and finish the Activity2 else display Gridview in Activity2.And also add one more thing in the `onConfigurationChanged` method check the new configuration and if it is portrait mode start Activity1 and finish the Activity2.

**How to check Configuration**

```
int getConf=this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if(getConf==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
    //Portrait
}else {
    //Landscape
}
```

**Activity1 should be like below**

```
int getConf=this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if(getConf==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity2.class))
    finish();
}
```

**Activity2 will looks like below**

```
int getConf=this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if(getConf==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity1.class))
    finish();
}
```

Same way you will have to override `onConfigurationChanged` method and check the orientation like we have check above and take appropriate action like we have start new activity and finish the current one.

Comment: Ok...now my question is if user hold its phone in landscape mode and start the app then according to ur logic which activity is open..i think its activity 2. But as u say the start of the app always open activity1.

Comment: There was a little typo mistake that I had written but now it is now perfect. According to my answer activity1 only run in portrait so as you say that if you run your application in landscape mode and if you try to start the application the Activity1 will be called but what happened is it will check configuration in onCreate method and it will find landscape orientation so it will start Activity2 and it will be finish.