# How to prevent screen autorotation but prevent activity from rotating

Tags: android, android-activity, accelerometer, autorotate

This may sound a newbie question anyway I'm new to Android development.

Basically what I need to do it to prevent the activity from changing its rotation but meanwhile I need to detect the device orientation change i.e. if device orientation has been changed from top to botton, or from top to left-portrait etc.

in iOS there is an analogue `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` where you can handle the device orientation change and tell the view if you want it to autorotate or not.
Please pay attention that no any manual data handling of accelerometer data.

So basically I want to detect DEVICE's orientation change and prevent Activity from rotating.
I'm also playing with data from Sensor to detect shake. But internally Android does some filtration of signals in order to decide when to rotate the UI. So basically I need to catch that event. Anyone can help ?

---

Simple formulation of my question : **I need to detect android device orientation change without playing manually with sensor data, while keeping activity orientation stick to some orientation**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure the out the solution.

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/08/orientationeventlistener-detect.html

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need to do if you want to fix one orientation to landscape, go the AndroidManifest and in your activity

```
<activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".LoginScreen" 
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

add this...if its portrait then change this to android:screenOrientation="portrait"

And for motion please refer to @thepoosh link that is 
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/a-quick-tutorial-on-coding-androids-accelerometer/472

Comment: Are you suggesting me to detect device orientation change my handling the data from sensor manually ? Guys I think there should be done lots of math filtering and so on. Isn't there any android native way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1):

what you're looking for is the XML `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` and use the sensors to find the position of the phone.

[android orientation.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

[accelerometer.](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/a-quick-tutorial-on-coding-androids-accelerometer/472)

Comment: As I got you suggest me to stick the user interface to be displayed only in landscape or portrait mode and detect the device orientation changes by playing manually with Sensor data ?

Comment: exactly, the sensors don't care about the view orientation, just the phone positioning.

Comment: See what I mean, android does automatic detection of device orientation change and activity orientation change automatically. So it means actually that android has already embedded filtering of sensor data i.e. system knows when activity orientation change should be performed. I mean if the system has already implemented algorithm of detecting the device orientation change, why the developer has to invent the wheel. Because basically the algorithm of detection is kind of tricky thing is requires data filtering from noise also filtering it from sudden shakes and so on.

Comment: So do I get it right that there is no any native way of handling the orientation change. I.e. I expect some callback function which is called if the device orientation is changed. hah if it doesn't hah i really never expected android to be so poorly interfaced.

Comment: there is no invention of wheels or any hackish things done here. sensors are the android way of enabling the programer to check the phone orientation

Comment: there is a way of knowing when the orientation changes. that wasn't your question. try reading on [runtime changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Comment: but do you understand that the detection of device orientation change is not a simple check like this   **if (event.values[1] < 6.5 && event.values[1] > -6.5) {
                Log.d("Sensor", "Protrait");
        } else {
                Log.d("Sensor", "Landscape");}** it really requires real data processing. I think it is really a wheel invention if developer implements it in **onSensorChanged**

Comment: **onConfigurationChanged** wont be called if I stick my activity to not change its orientation as you suggested using this in manifest **android:screenOrientation="portrait"**. Also my qeustion was very simple **I want to detect DEVICE's orientation change and prevent Activity from rotating** and I'm looking for some legacy way of doing it. Of course if android does have it at all. (Playing manually with sensor data would be the worse solution i think)

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457659/android-onconfigurationchanged-not-being-called

Comment: @deimus, you should try and accept this question and ask a new one. comments won't help the next Google searcher in finding his answer

Comment: man please read my question carefully, I've asked exactly what I need here. Quote : **in iOS there is an analogue - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation where you can handle the device orientation change and tell the view if you want it to autorotate or not. Please pay attention that no any manual data handling of accelerometer data.**

Comment: I read it, the link on runtime changes includes the `onConfigurationChanged` function that will trigger when the phone changes orientation.

Comment: Playing with sensor data is not solution as far as I understand now. Of course if you can provide some info that android doesn't support legacy way of doing it, I might accept your answer as a solution. Yet I think your answer is not a solution.

Comment: onConfiguration change **will not** be triggered if I stick my activity to some orientation in manifest e.g. as you said **android:screenOrientation="portrait"**. See it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457659/android-onconfigurationchanged-not-being-called

Comment: you can either use the sensors and `android:screenOrientation` and sensors or the function. I have to say that don't really get what you want. if you're already using the sensors what's your problem?! please come to the freenode irc channel #android-dev for more info

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13099/discussion-between-deimus-and-thepoosh)

Comment: my question was/is very simple : **I need to detect android device orientation change without playing manually with sensor data, while keeping activity orientation stick to some orientation**

Comment: figured out I just had to listen to OrientationEventListener

Comment: thanks for the interesting dicussion and your time +1 from me

Comment: enjoyed it (most of the time =] )