# Android AsyncTask ProgressDialog rotation different configurations

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog, screen-rotation

I have managed to use an Asynctask with an indeterminate progress bar during screen rotation. Asynctask starts only once, progress bar is restored on rotation just as I wanted.

I have different layouts for portrait and layout orientations. Layouts include a button and a textview. The size and text color of textview in layout-land is different. And the orientation is landscape.

The problem is when I rotate the screen while asynctask is running, it cant update the textview in onPostExecute method. When I rotate, it recreates the activity with layout-land file. But why I cant update my Textview?

**layout\activity_main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button 
        android:text="Start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="startClicked"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hello"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**layout-land\activity_main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button 
        android:text="Start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="startClicked"
        />
    <TextView
        android:textSize="36dp"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:id="@+id/hello"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.asynctaskconfig;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        static String data;
        static ProgressDialog pd;
        MyAsyncTask task;
        TextView tv;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);

            if (getLastNonConfigurationInstance() != null) {
                task = (MyAsyncTask) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
                if (task != null) {
                    if (!(task.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED))) {
                        showProgressDialog();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
            if (pd != null)
                pd.dismiss();
            if (task != null)
                return (task);
            return super.onRetainNonConfigurationInstance();
        }


        private void showProgressDialog() {
            if (pd == null || !pd.isShowing()) {
                pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                pd.setIndeterminate(true);
                pd.setTitle("DOING..");
                pd.show();
            }
        }

        private void dismissProgressDialog() {
            if (pd != null && pd.isShowing())
                pd.dismiss();
        }

        public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                showProgressDialog();
            }

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    data = "result from ws";
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                if (result) {
                    dismissProgressDialog();
                    updateUI();
                }
            }
        }

        private void updateUI() {
            tv.setText(data == null ? "null" : data);
        }

        public void startClicked(View target) {
            task = new MyAsyncTask();
            task.execute("start");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have done is as follows:

**1-** Add `android:freezesText="true"` to all my TextViews. This enables TextViews to save their states on configuration changes.

**2-** Make your AsyncTask a `static inner class.`

**3-** Modify `AsyncTask` to keep a reference to the Activity it lives in. So AsyncTask can access UI widgets of Activity via this reference.

**4-** Here, it is important to keep a valid activity reference during screen rotations. So, override `onDestroy` method and unbind the Activity from AsyncTask. Thus, task wont keep the old(died) activity.

**5-** In `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance`, if task is still running, update its activity reference with the current activity, so it is successfully tied to new activity.

**6-** Finally, in `onPostExecuteMethod`, access the UI elements of the Activity via activity reference.

Complete Working Solution:

> layout\activity_main.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button 
        android:text="Start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="startClicked"
        />
    <TextView
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:id="@+id/hello"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> layout-land\activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button 
        android:text="Start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="startClicked"
        />
    <TextView
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:textSize="36dp"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:id="@+id/hello"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.asynctaskconfig;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    static ProgressDialog pd;
    MyAsyncTask task;
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);

        if (getLastNonConfigurationInstance() != null) {
            task = (MyAsyncTask) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
            if (task != null) {
                task.activity = this;
                if (!(task.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED))) {
                    showProgressDialog();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (task != null) {
            task.activity = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
        if (pd != null)
            pd.dismiss();
        if (task != null)
            return (task);
        return super.onRetainNonConfigurationInstance();
    }

    private void showProgressDialog() {
        if (pd == null || !pd.isShowing()) {
            pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pd.setIndeterminate(true);
            pd.setTitle("DOING..");
            pd.show();
        }
    }

    private void dismissProgressDialog() {
        if (pd != null && pd.isShowing())
            pd.dismiss();
    }

    static class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        MainActivity activity;

        public MyAsyncTask(MainActivity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            activity.showProgressDialog();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(8000);
                return "data from ws";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "exception";
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            activity.dismissProgressDialog();
            activity.tv.setText(result == null ? "null" : result);
        }
    }

    public void startClicked(View target) {
        task = new MyAsyncTask(this);
        task.execute("start");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
private void updateUI() {
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
    tv.setText(data == null ? "null" : data);
}
```

If that fails, is it possibly a timing-issue? That is, could it be the task completed during the orientation change? Just to be on the safe side, you could modify your `onCreate` method by adding an `updateUI()` call if task has finished:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);

        if (getLastNonConfigurationInstance() != null) {
            task = (MyAsyncTask) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
            if (task != null) {
                if (!(task.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED))) {
                    showProgressDialog();
                } else
                    updateUI();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work because tv will still be the TextView of the old activity.

Comment: yes. but what is the solution? Why cant we access the new tv?

Comment: @ekholm, that shouldn't be the case, because the onCreate is called on orientation change, and should be inflating the orientation-specific layout.
Tim, could you add some break-points to onCreate to verify it is indeed called and the TextView resolves. For test-purposes, rename one of the TextViews to tvHelloLand and see if FindViewById can find it. If so, the ugly solution would be to find tvHello first, and if it's null, find tvHelloLand. In theory, your solution should work, as it finds the TextView after the layout is inflated.

Comment: still no luck. Textview is inflated 2 times, on the second one, it gets it from landscape layout I think. but still doesnt update its text.

Comment: Ok, now we're in debugging mode ;) Add some Log.d and dump the content of "data" on update, so you know you're actually changing something... and/or set a known changed text. (i.e. static int count = 1; tv.setText( String.format( "My text: %d", count++ ) ); )

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case is essentially that the TextView you are trying to change is no longer the TextView visible on the screen. The rotation caused Android to discard the old Activity and building a new one - complete with all views in the xml file. Thus, your TextView 'tv' is still part of the old activity, changes will just do nothing.

The easiest way now to get the behavior you want, is to just look again for the textview, i.e., use "findViewById" again in your updateUI method and you should be fine!

Comment: findViewById will still find the TextView of the old Activity, because its views are inflated in its setContentView().

Answer (score 0):

In this case you probably don't want the activity to be recreated on orientation changes. You may handle the orientation changes within your activity by adding this to your activity in your manifest:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Then override onConfigurationChanged:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
}
```

Comment: No, I want it to be recreated every time. I am using a layout-land\activity_main.xml for exactly this purpose.

Comment: yes, but the correct view will be inflated when calling setContentView

Comment: no? Did you verify that activity is not recreated and that tv gets a new value?

Comment: Then that is the problem. You may find clues in this thread: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457659/android-onconfigurationchanged-not-being-called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457659/android-onconfigurationchanged-not-being-called)

Comment: ok. this updates the textview with text "result from ws" but when I rotate it back, the layout is restored to original state in which textview content is "hello world". What to do when we go back from landscape to portrait again.

Comment: You could just keep the current text string as a field in the Activity and set it to the TextView each time it has been inflated. Or, for a more robust solution, use SharedPreferences or content provider.