# Android 2.3.3 & 4.1.2 android:configChanges for detecting Orientation change

Tags: android, android-orientation

I am building an app with Android 2.3.3 API. I need to recognize the change in orientation and perform some action. So I added the following in Android Manifest,

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden
```

And I override the method

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
```

It works perfect on Android 2.3.3. But when I install the same app (built with 2.3.3 API) on a 4.1.2, onConfigurationChanged() is not invoked. I searched online for solution and people suggest to add the following in android manifest.

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

If I build the app with above statement and built with 4.1.2 API, It works perfect on 4.1.2 device. But I cannot install it on 2.3.3. 2.3.3 API doesn't have "screenSize" option. So to support both, what should I do?

Thanks, Karthik

Comment: Possible duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457659/android-onconfigurationchanged-not-being-called & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620033/onconfigurationchanged-not-getting-called

Comment: Those does not help to my situation. As I said, they suggest me to add "screenSize". But it is not supported in 2.3.3 API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Look at mine AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" 
    android:maxSdkVersion="16"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity 
        android:name=".ConfigrationTask"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: I see no "screenSize" in your manifest file. Does it still work on 4.1.2?

Comment: Yes,method is called,FYI I tested this application android 4.0

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy.. I really dont understand the logic behind it.. But it works.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just because you compile against, or target, a given API level does not mean you cannot explicitly support lower API levels.  Try adding something like the following to your manifest.  I took the levels from the versions mentioned in your question.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
```

Comment: I actually had the following in my code. But no use. <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

Comment: And with that, it refuses to install on a 2.3.3 device?

Comment: No, It installs on 2.3.3 if I build with 2.3.3 API. I mean, Project Properties -> Android -> Android 2.3.3 and build.

Answer (score 1):

FYI Look Below code that i did used :

```
    @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if(newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"On Config Change LANDSCAPE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"On Config Change PORTRAIT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note this point in your case : 
[config changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) 
The screen orientation has changed — the user has rotated the device.
Note: If your application targets API level 13 or higher (as declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), then you should also declare the "screenSize" configuration, because it also changes when a device switches between portrait and landscape orientations.

Thank you

Comment: Did you read my full question? I said I cant add "screenSize" Because I am building the app with 2.3.3 API.

Comment: If your target version and min sdk version is lower then API level 13 then like i tested the method was called look at                         <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" 
        android:maxSdkVersion="16"/>