# public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) is not calling

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android onConfigurationChanged not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457659/android-onconfigurationchanged-not-being-called)

I Have the same problem.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.sailbook.MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

I set a breakpoint, but the debugger does not hold if i turn the phone  in "onConfigurationChanged".

I want that the main activity does not recreated when I turn the phone. But the content should rotate.

Comment: please search before asking

Comment: Thx. I was looking for. I also found items, but they have not helped me.