# onConfigurationChanged not called (Android 2.2)

Tags: android

I already found a bunch of similar problems related with this topic and I knew the solution was to append "screenSize" to the android:configChanges attribute(please refer to [onConfigurationChanged not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620033/onconfigurationchanged-not-getting-called) if you're interested). But it does not work for my situation.

My application was built on Android 2.2(API level 8) and the device is installed with 2.3(API level 9).
Any clues? Thank you in advance.

Related Manifest.xml fragments have been attached:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name="com.erlinyou.Erlinyou"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"                  
                  android:configChanges="orientation">                  
                  android:launchMode="singleInstance">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Inside the activity tag from your AndroidManifest.xml do you have android:configChanges="orientation" ?

Comment: Sure. I check it carefully.

Comment: post your manifest and the code where you override onConfigurationChanged

Comment: It has been attached. BTW, I happened to find the related topic of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457659/android-onconfigurationchanged-not-being-called?rq=1 already answered my question. There exist quite a few calls to setRequestedOrientation in my codes. And it works after I remove them all. Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: One related topic of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457659/android-onconfigurationchanged-not-being-called?rq=1 already answered the question.

Comment: did you override onConfigurarionChanged? May I see you code?

Comment: One related topic of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457659/android-onconfigurationchanged-not-being-called?rq=1 already answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

**onConfigurationChanged **

The onConfigurationChanged method.. only above 3.2 api

Comment: the View.onConfigurationChanged has been introduced with the api 3.2. The Activity one is from api level 1

Comment: ok.. Mr.blackbelt but onConfigurationChanged method not called below 3.2 why

Comment: You have to ask to the OP not me .  I was only pointing out the incompleteness of your answer

Comment: as suggested by @blackbelt check the link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)

Comment: @Raghunandan: can u help me pls

Comment: @Raghunandan: Yeah, I did read the specification for this API though I do not finish the full page. But I still cannot figure out a solution for my problem. Any more detailed guidance?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your setting of **targetSdkVersion**. See below explanation from Google. It means:

for targetSdkVersion is **lower than 13(HONEYCOMB_MR2)**, set    ***android:configChanges="orientation"*** for your Activity.

for targetSdkVersion **is or greater 13(HONEYCOMB_MR2)**, set ***android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"*** for your Activity.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#configChanges
screenSize The current available screen size has changed. If applications don't target at least HONEYCOMB_MR2 then the activity will always handle this itself (the change will not result in a restart). This represents a change in the currently available size, so will change when the user switches between landscape and portrait.

Hope it works for you.