# OnConfigurationChanged not called in mono android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm trying to get the screen rotation event. For that I'm using "OnConfigurationChanged".

The problem is my Activity definition which looks like

```
[Activity(ConfigurationChanges = global::Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation | global::Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden)]
```

I'm not able to provide the configuration global::Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.SreenSize which leads to the problem, that OnConfigurationChanged is not called.

My workaround is to add to the configuration to the AndroidManifest.xml which is kind of a hack.

```
<activity
        android:name="mpa.gui.android.activities.HomeActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
</activity>
```

I'm using 
- Visual Studio 2012.
- My android project targets API level is 17
- Minimum Android target is set to Android 2.3

the AndroidManifest also configures this

Any idea why i can't configure the ScreemSize in my Activity?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: My guess is because you have `Android` in your namespace things get confused.

Comment: Hope that this is not the problem :) would be kind of silly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to OR `Android.Content.Pm.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize` to trigger the `onConfigurationChanged` event for screen orientation changes in versions of Android higher than API level 13.

EG:

```
[Activity(Label = "MyActivity", ConfigurationChanges=Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation|Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize)]
```

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7366180/1099111