# Locale: onConfigurationChanged not called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-manifest, locale

I want my language to change dynamically and I am trying to use onConfigurationChanged but it is not being called. I have a MainActivity that creates my action bar and viewpager. The rest of my pages are Fragments. In my SettingsFragment I have a button to switch the language to French.

```
langChange.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View vi) {
            MainActivity main = (MainActivity)getActivity();
            main.langChange();
        }

});
```

Then in my MainActivity I have

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (locale != null){
        newConfig.locale = locale;
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}

public void langChange(){
    if(currentLanguage == FRENCH_LANGUAGE){
        locale = new Locale("en");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration c = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
        c.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(c,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        currentLanguage = "English";
    }
    else if(currentLanguage == ENGLISH_LANGUAGE){
        locale = new Locale("fr");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration c = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
        c.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(c,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        currentLanguage = "French";
    }
    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(actionBar.getTabCount() - 1); //This just puts it back to the settings tab
}
```

The `onConfigurationChanged` is not being called. In my manifest I have:

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="locale"></activity>
```

I have tried adding one or all of these options `orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize` with no success.

The reason for all of this is because I want to change the actionBar text and all the other text once I click the button. I have a separate strings file for French.

Any help would be great.

Comment: How do you know that `onConfigurationChanged` isn't called? You have a check for `null` around the code inside the method, that could possibly be the problem. Also take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457659/android-onconfigurationchanged-not-being-called

Comment: I added breakpoints before and after the if statement with `Log.d` as well. I know it doesn't hit this method. I have also looked at the question above and those answers don't solve my issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I've looked into this a bit.

I'm not sure, why the `onConfigurationChanged` method isn't called, so I'm hoping someone can enlighten us on this part.

In my search I stumbled upon this [tutorial](http://snowpard-android.blogspot.dk/2013/03/programmatically-change-language-in.html) , which actually change the `Locale`, by changing the configuration.

Your code looks a lot like this tutorial actually ;-)

Anyways, the important thing about the tutorial and the code is this method:

```
private void updateTexts() {
    txt_hello.setText(R.string.hello_world);
    btn_en.setText(R.string.btn_en);
    btn_ru.setText(R.string.btn_ru);
    btn_fr.setText(R.string.btn_fr);
    btn_de.setText(R.string.btn_de);
}
```

This is where the "magic" happens; after you've changed your locale you will need to reload your resources and since you told Android you want to handle some configurations on your own you need to specifically reload all your text, by setting your UI items texts again.

When this is done, the app will load the strings from the specific locales folder.

The answer to why Android behaves this way, can be found in the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for the `Activity` saying:

> [...]
>
> This is done because any application resource, including layout files, can change based on any configuration value. Thus the only safe way to handle a configuration change is to re-retrieve all resources, including layouts, drawables, and strings. Because activities must already know how to save their state and re-create themselves from that state, this is a convenient way to have an activity restart itself with a new configuration.

The guy writing the tutorial was kind enough to add the whole tutorial project as a download, so I recommend you go check it out to see how it's working, because it is working ;-) You can outcomment the `onConfigurationChanged` method, as it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are a god for finding this. It is perfect. A couple of changes I have to do to fit it around my code but works perfectly!!!! Thanks

Comment: Any time - I love digging around ;-)

Answer (score 21):

**You have to define android:configChanges="layoutDirection|locale" in order for onConfigurationChanged() to be called.**

Comment: He is totally right, adding `layoutDirection` works, without not.

Comment: That also worked for me, did you have any idea whats the background behind that?