# Detect system language change

Tags: android, locale

I want to be informed in my Application class when the system language is changed. 
My Application class:

```
class MyApp : Application() {

    override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration?) {
        Log.d("yyy", "onConfigurationChanged, old locale " + resources.configuration.locale + " new locale " + newConfig?.locale)
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
    }

}
```

I would assume that, if comparing the current locale to the new locale *before* calling `super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)`, they would differ, but when I set the system locale to e.g. `En_US` in the Android settings app, `resources.configuration.locale` already returns `En_US` (and the new config does too), so there is no way for me to check if the locale way actually changed.

My solution would be to save the selected locale in the applications `onCreate()` and compare it with the new locale in `onConfigurationChanged()`.

1. Is there a more elegant way?
2. Why does `onConfigurationChanged` behave that way?

Comment: You can compare old locale to the new one right in onCreate()

Comment: @LeoLeontev I want to have a callback when the locale is changed while the application is running.

Comment: Found answer to the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27648673/6120487

Comment: @LeoLeontev onConfigurationChanged IS called, that's not the problem.