# How to hide certain view while android keyboard is shown?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I am trying to write a code to hide certain ui elements while Android Keyboard is shown , i tried to add "adjustResize" in the manifest but it re-sizing the elements automatically but not hiding some of the views in the layout.

**MyCode:**

```
package com.example.code;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


    // Checks whether a hardware keyboard is available
    if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard hidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No above", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}  }
```

**XML :**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="300dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image_back"/>
</ScrollView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/xyz"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Test Layout"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/abc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/xyz"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Please enter text"
    android:textSize="40sp" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.code"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.code.MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Screenshots:**

[image]

So , these are above codes and screenshot of my app , so i am want hide the "**Test Layout**" textview while keyboard is open. So , please suggest me some technique and solution for my issue.

Comment: Is there any scrollview with this layout ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this and update the visibility of your layout according to the visibility of the keyboard.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


    // Checks whether a hardware keyboard is available
    if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard hidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: The same way. You can override the onConfigurationChanged method in a Fragment as well

Comment: but i tried your code but onConfigurationChanged is not called even i have given android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" in the activity in manifest

Comment: It can be a number of things. You can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6457930/1067744) for some ideas on why it's not called.

Comment: yes i already check that post , but i applied everything , please go through my updated code .. you can get to know properly.

Comment: yes the method gets called , when i change the orientation of the device means portrait to landscape but how can i called when i press the edittext then keyboard pops-up , at that time i need to check whether keyboard is open or not.

Comment: Don't know why it's not working then. Alternatively you could hide/show it when your EditText is focused/unfocused. <your-edit-text>.setOnFocusChangeListener(...);

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Hide button when keyboard is open*/
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new 
ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    Rect r = new Rect();
    view.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

    int heightDiff = view.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);

    if (heightDiff > 244) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
        //ok now we know the keyboard is up...
        buttonLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    } else {
        //ok now we know the keyboard is down...
        buttonLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    }
}
});
```