# onConfigurationChanged is not triggered

Tags: android, orientation

I want to set activity configuration depending on device rotation.

I handle the rotation using below method:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
.....
}
```

It works rotate from portrait to landscape. Callback triggers and the app's orientation is changed.

But it is not triggered rotating around the device when it is landscape. But the app's orientation is changed.

I added below lines into manifest.

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
> ```
>
> android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

How can I handle it?

Answer (score 0):

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" rather than android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Ensure that you are not calling

`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

anywhere. This will cause `onConfigurationChange()` to not fire.

Also,Check that you are not using `android:screenOrientation` in your `manifest`.

or , in java code  `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

to force the orientation of your `Activity` to portrait mode, you're not candidate to receive orientation changes.

So the solution is to not `setRequestOrientation` to a particular mode. But instead use `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR`.

referance : [Android onConfigurationChanged not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457659/android-onconfigurationchanged-not-being-called)